# Decoding the chinese characters in input text field

Tags: javascript, text, decodeuricomponent

I want to decode the chinese characters into the input text field.But it is showing the field as it is.

But it is showing the "&#28450 ;&#23383 ;" instead of chinese characters

**Expected output :漢字

output :&#28450 ;&#23383 ;**

it is working fine when i use textarea

input type="text" id="chinese"

function myFunction() {

```
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent("&#28450;&#23383;")
document.getElementById("chinese").value= uri_dec;
```

}

Please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`decodeURIComponent` doesn't do what you think it does. It will decode `"%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97"` (an URI-encoded string) into `"漢字"`; but you have *HTML entities*, not an URI-encoded string.

```js
var ent_enc = "&#28450;&#23383;"
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = ent_enc;
var ent_dec = div.textContent;
document.getElementById("chinese").value = ent_dec;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="chinese">
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` usage is unsafe if your input could be untrusted. For example, `var ent_enc = "<img src=/ onerror=alert(1)>"` leads to code execution. Using `document.createElement('textarea')` would be safer, as it can't have any child nodes beyond plain text.